# How to get my VM on Azure to allow in My SQL Connection?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, virtual-machines, azure

I have a Virtual Machine that is running my web api. I have then created a SQL Database through Azure(this db is not on the VM) and I put that connection string in my application.

I get this when I try to run it. What do I need to do to solve this?

My connection string

```
"Server=tcp:database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyApp;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=MyUserName;Password=MyPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"






Server Error in '/' Application.

The system cannot find the file specified

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +1394
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1120
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +910
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +114
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1631
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +267
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +211
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +393
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +104
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +509
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass33.<UsingConnection>b__32() +567
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +15
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +238
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +916
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript) +117
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +212
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +135
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +175
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +116
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +121
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +293
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +187
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +483
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input) +177
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action) +274
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +38
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +77
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +59
   System.Linq.Queryable.Any(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +59
   PantryApp.Framework.Services.UnitTypeService.CreateDefaults() +333
   PantryApp.Api.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() +81

[HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +544
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +186
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +402
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +343

[HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +712
```

Comment: Your connection string shows the server name as database.windows.net. Is this actually what you have or did you remove the first part?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

1. Your connection string says "Server=tcp:database.windows.net" it should be .database.windows.net. You might have just removed this from your post for privacy, but wanted to check.
2. Have you ticked the box in teh Azure SQL firewall to allow access from Azure? If you don't have this traffic from your VM won't be allowed in. Either tick the box, or if you want to be more specific add a firewall rule on the Azure SQL Instance to allow traffic from your VM's public IP. This must be a public IP as it's a PaaS service, and generally you want to to be static.

Comment: Yes I removed the first part of my tcp:. I do have "Allow access to Azure services" as "on". I also tried to add the VM Virtual Public IP to the allowed firewall list though I am not sure if this is the right IP.

Comment: Are you able to connect to to teh DB from management studio from your PC (once you allow the IP through the firewall)?

Comment: Yes on my local computer I can connect to the azure db, I can run locally my webstie and connect to my db as well. I also went to the vm and installed telnet and did telnet "myname.database.windows.net" 1443 and it seemed like it connected.

Comment: I also just disabled the VM firewall and still get the same error.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your website. What language is it in? Do you have the appropriate drivers installed.

Comment: asp.net web api. I can access any endpoint that has no database connection.

Comment: Have you tried making a connection manually from the VM either using SSMS or ODBC manager?

Comment: No, how would I do that?

Comment: Log on to your VM using RDP and either download and install SQL server management studio, or use the built in ODBC console to create a test connection.